# Table cells equal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make all the table cells equal to the image size, but for some reason, they won't be set to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzkhW/

HTML(shortened a bit)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/CMu2qnB.png"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border:1px solid black;
}
td {width:206px;
    height:214px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working if the page is wide enough.  You can try setting an additional "min-width: 206px;" on the td styles to override the collapse induced by the page width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min-width`, to set the minimum width, of the `<td>` elements, in place of `width`, for example: `min-width:206px;` ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gzkhW/1/)).

The problem with `width` seems to be that the `<table>` element tries, or is made to, respect the width of the parent element or viewport. Making this wider will allow the `<td>` elements to stretch to the specified size; otherwise it'll be constrained. `min-width` 'solves' this by *forcing* the minimum, thereby forcing the `<table>` to expand beyond the constraints of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

try to add to your table style some width as you want

```
width:2060px;

height:2140px;
```

for example,you can customize this values in order to fix the table cells i hope i helped you...